# Точки над i или ё?

Tags: стилистика

"Поставить точки над i" — значит, окончательно разобраться в вопросе, уточнить все моменты. Но частенько я встречаю фразу "поставить точки над ё". Понятно, что буквы i в русском языке сейчас нет, но так звучит привычнее. Но как все-таки правильно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По мне, вполне нормативный фразеологизм. Выражение молодое, но думаю со временем вариант с I вытеснит, также как "от а до я" вытеснила выражение "от аза до ижицы". Фразеологизм "точки над ё" уже зафиксирован в словаре "Живая речь. Словарь разговорных выражений". Другое дело, что " точки над i" вариант пока более литературный и в речи стремящийся к официальности пока лучше использовать вариант с "i".

Comment: Честно говоря, первый раз слышу такой фразеологизм.

Comment: Не думаю, что ё заменит и. Ё - буква какая-то несерьёзная и в выражении про обстоятельность смотрится неуместно.

В детстве воспринимал это выражение как расставить галочки над й.

Comment: Вот-вот. Я тоже так в детстве думала.

Comment: > выражении про обстоятельность  
  
Опаньки! А как Вы трактуете это выражение? 

Если по сути, то я тоже крепко сомневаюсь, что Ё вытеснит I.

Comment: @behemothus, под выражением я понимаю "уточнить, прояснить все детали". Подобные действия у менч ассоциируются с обстоятельностью.

Comment: Хм... А у меня скорее с вызовом на откровенность... В крайнем случае - с окончанием такого откровенного разговора... Шут его знает, может оно действительно "обстоятельность"...

Answer (score 0):

Эвфемизм, несёт ярко выраженную брутальную, вульгарную окраску, используя исконную форму выражения

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).